# convert character to int - swift 3

Tags: swift3

I need to do some calculation from the character in an array.

```
let characters = Array(number.characters)
total += Int(characters[i]) * multipliers[i]
```

This array is something like ["8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "2", "3"].

> I'm getting an error as "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with
>   an argument list of type '(String.CharacterView._Element)"

I tried this with no luck

```
total += String(characters[i]).toInt() * multipliers[i]
```

Can someone help me to solve this? How to convert characters into int in swift3?

Comment: `Int(String(characters[i]))`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks man. This works for me.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: @LeoDabus why don't you create an actual answer so it can be marked as the answer.

Comment: @ZuseeWeekin Why don't you mark it as the answer so Leo get's credit?

Answer (score 1):

try 
total += String(Int(characters[i])) * multipliers[i]

Comment: This does not work.  You probably meant Int(String(characters[i])) * multipliers[i]